# UICollectionView Appearing Blank

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to use a UICollectionView but I am having a lot of issues. I have a UIViewController with a UICollectionView inside. I have setup all the delegates correctly along with the UILabel in the CVcell. The view appears and is white as defined in the code. The NSLog sends out all the cells and the text that should be there but in the actual UICollectionView it is blank and nothing appears apart from the scroll view. I have tried everything but cannot seem to get this working correctly. The cell is 187 x 187 taking up half the screen size with a label in the middle. I will post the code below.

Thanks

[image: Delegate]

```
#import "StudentControllerMain.h"
#import "CVcell.h"



@interface StudentControllerMain ()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataArray;


@end

@implementation StudentControllerMain





- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *firstSection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        [firstSection addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", i]];
    }

    self.dataArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstSection, nil];




    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CVcell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CVcell"];


    // Configure layout

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    self.collectionView = nil;
    self.dataArray = nil;
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/




-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return [self.dataArray count];
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSMutableArray *sectionArray = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionArray count];


}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Setup cell identifier
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CVcell";
    CVcell *cell = (CVcell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableArray *data = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSString *cellData = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(cellData);
    [cell.title setText:cellData];
    [cell.title setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    return cell;

}


@end
```

Comment: show the code that sets the delegate.

Comment: I posted an image above

Answer (score 2):

1. remove the register class code;
2. setting the "identifier" attribute (in attribute inspector) of collection view cell in storyboard;

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure cellForItemAtIndexPath is being called then the issue is the frame of all the views as they are laid out. Run the app and go to that page. Go to Debug -> View debugging -> Capture view hierarchy . This will show you all the views and their sizes. Do you see the table itself? Is it the correct height? Can you see each cell? Can you see their subviews? You can right click each one to print out their dimensions.

Comment: Yeah, I can see all the cells that should be there so it seems like it is just the label is not setting correctly.

Comment: Then that pretty much narrows down your problem. Try cell.title.text = cellData

Comment: Tried, same problem. I feel like nothing is appearing from the custom cell because if I change the background colour, it does not display in the view also..

Comment: also, if I change that label tag to something that does not exist in the cell view it will give me an error so it recognises that it is there it just does not seem to display it in the UICollectionView

Comment: After setting the title can you confirm that the frame of the title label is correct?

Comment: in the debug I only see the cell, I don't see the label as a frame.

Comment: That might be your problem. Going into your implemetation of the custom cell and try to print out its frame. It might have a width and height of 0.

Comment: width and height of the cell is 187 so that does not seem to be it.

Comment: Not the cell. The label that is being set.

Comment: width of the label is 125 and the height is 25. I have a strong feeling the custom view is not appearing in the collection view but I have no idea why.

Comment: Try also checking debug-> view debugging -> show view frames. Do this to make sure all the parents are being laid out. Also try manually adding borders with layer.borderColor and layer.borderWidth. This way you can be sure its your custom cell that is being used.

Comment: The uilabel is not showing up in the view frames. also the borders don't show up too which is confirming my theory of the custom view not being displayed. any way to fix this?

Comment: Breakpoint at the line CVcell *cell = (CVcell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; to make sure the correct class is being used. Also you might have to register the class [_collectionView registerClass:[CVcell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

Comment: added the break point and it breaks so it is going through the method correctly

Comment: When you capture view hierarchy and you right click the cell is it the correct class?